# SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS gives syntax error for H2 db

Tags: mysql, count, h2

I am using H2 for JUnit of my Spring Boot application.

One of my DAO classes uses `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` in a query for pagination, which produces syntax error for H2 db while running the JUnit test. I am using MySQL for dev.

My query looks like

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS column1, column2 
FROM table
```

and the error is

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS column1, column2 from `table`;]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS" not found; SQL statement:
>   ELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS column1, column2 from `table`; [42122-196]

What could be work around to make it work for both?

Note: It is more of a dev related question, putting it here incase any `DBA` can help.

Comment: May we see the text of the query and the error?

Comment: @RickJames Sorry for the delayed response, pls see the question.

Comment: Alas.  Yet another reason to shun 3rd party packages.  I _guess_ that H2 (or something) is parsing the query to find the columns, but doing a bad job of it.

Comment: @RickJames I guess there is no such functionality in H2 yet, it just looks for it as a column. I am using `count(*)` to make it work, which is said to be fast as well. It just adds few extra line of code for using it for pagination.

Comment: @RickJames I Can't understand what you mean by your comment, are you saying that people should implement their own databases from scratch?! How exactly H2 not supporting some obscure mysql syntax is "doing bad job"?! Why would it support a non standard syntax from a different database?

Comment: Every DB vendor has non-standard syntax.  Every 3rd party software supports "most" of the DB's syntax.  Most users of 3rd party software venture into some gray area where the 3rd party mapping on to DB syntax / optimization / etc is less than perfect.  In this case, you reached into MySQL's syntax and got burned by H2's incomplete implementation.  Perhaps you could take the `CREATE TABLEs` H2 made, remove H2 from the picture, and forge ahead.

Comment: It seems that the number of keystrokes needed to create a `SELECT` is _more_  when done via 3rd party "objects", "mappings", "methods", than simply learning an writing SQL.  And you have to learn 2 languages!  SQL _and_ the mapping to it.  Sorry, I get on this tirade sometimes.

Comment: @RickJames ok, now I understand where your confusion is coming from. H2 **is not** a 3rd party software used to access mysql. It's a **DB vendor**.

Comment: Oh.  Then why is the Question tagged [mysql]?  `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is (I think) unique to MySQL.  Does H2 also recognize it?  Apparently not.

Comment: @RickJames Yes, it's unique to mysql. OP is using mysql in production and H2 for testing. For some reason he thinks that this is good practice.

Comment: That way, OP will have to degrade his app to the least-common-denominator, missing out on the added features of each RDBMS.  Ugh.

Comment: @RickJames @Oleg thanks guys. @RickJames Yes, I am using `count(*)` for now. Regarding the duplicate question: I was desperate to find out the answer, I posted this question on SO and DBA exchange, so this question is migrated from there, making it duplicate. I have voted to close the other question.